# Is it possible to set min go version required?

Tags: go

`./get_url.go:29:14: client.CloseIdleConnections undefined (type *http.Client has no field or method CloseIdleConnections)`

Above error is because [CloseIdleConnections](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Client.CloseIdleConnections) was added recently in Go ver 1.12, and my initial version was older:

```
$ go version
go version go1.11.4 linux/amd64
```

Is there a way we can set the min go version required in the .go files?

Comment: in your case i would use an interface to figure out if `*http.Client` implements `CloseIdleConnections`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the specific go version you want your file to be built with using a build tag:

```golang
// This file will now build with go version 1.9
// +build go1.9
package foo

...
```

Ref. https://golang.org/pkg/go/build/#hdr-Build_Constraints